# Can an abstract data type be made from another abstract data type?

Tags: oop, object, language-agnostic, terminology, abstract-data-type

From my understanding, an abstract data type is a data type that has an abstract representation and can be implemented in many ways for its core functionalities. It is the opposite of a concrete data type. In most books or classes they describe that the abstract data types should be implemented by concrete data types. Could not an abstract data type be implemented by another abstract data type? Technically, there are always various projects or questions that ask us to implement a stack with a queue, which is another abstract data type. Maybe I am misunderstanding something, which led me to ask here. Conceptually or in the design of languages are abstract data types always made by concrete data types or are/can they be made by other abstract data types? Why depending on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, by you can implement the abstract data type Set using the abstract data type Map (by modelling a Set entry `e` with a Map entry of `e -> dummyValue` to indicate its presence). This is how Java's HashSet is done, it uses HashMap internally.

Another example would be a Stack (which can be implemented using a List).